# Lipschitz continuous wrt second variable when second variable is a vector - is this how you check it?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the second order non-linear ODE $$x''=t^3+x^3.$$
Let's say that we want to see if this ODE has local existence and uniqueness. Of course, we are going to try to use the Cauchy-Lipschitz Theorem. So, we must consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}, f(t, x)=t^3+x_1^3$, where $x=(x_1, x_2)$ (I skip the part where I reduce the equation to a system of order one via a change of variables; I think that this is a well known procedure).

Now I need to see whether $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with respect to the second variable, that is $x$. For this I need to see whether the function $f$ is $C^1$ wrt x (this is not necessary, but it is sufficient and easy to check). Here comes my question: is it true that $f$ is $C^1$ wrt $x$ if and only if $f$ is $C^1$ wrt $x_1$ and $x_2$? Because if this is true, then things get trivial and, in general, I should simply compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ and see if this is also continuous.

P.S.: I know that this is probably some trivial calculus fact, but I haven't encountered it yet and I want to make sure that my intuition is correct.

Comment: Yes. It is trivially true. Just notice that $\partial f/\partial x_2=0$.

Comment: @GReyes thanks, I just wanted to make sure that I got it right that I must differentiate wrt every component of $x$ (I wasn't really sure how to differentiate wrt a vector)

Comment: You differentiate with respect to a vector by taking the gradient.

Comment: @GReyes I see, and if every component of the gradient is continuous, then my function is $C^1$ (this is also basically what I did because I also wanted to differentiate wrt every component of $x$)

Comment: That is exactly right.